# Import mail from Google apps to Postfix/Dovecot Maildir

Tags: postfix, dovecot, g-suite, mailbox, maildir

I was using **Google apps for work** and now I set up my own mail server since I have a lot of users and paying Google would be too much for that number :(

Currently my `Postfix` and `Dovecot` are set to use `Maildir/`.
I downloaded backup of mails from Google.
But, how to import that into my server since I am using `Mailid/` and the file that I get from Google is `All mail Including Spam and Trash.mbox`

Do I need to reconfigure Postfix and Dovecot to Mailbox instead of Maildir or there is some other way to import that data.

Everything is working just fine except I need to import that old mails from Google.

Sorry, but I am completely new in Mail server configuration.

Comment: The Dovecot manual covers a number of tools to convert mbox files Maildir: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Migration/MailFormat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you still have access to Google apps mail using imap protocol then you can use imapsync tool to copy all mail from one account to another regardless of their storage backend.

Comment: +1 for IMAP Sync, I used https://github.com/rgrove/larch